# Daw software that understand about notes and chords

Tags: daw

This question is very specific. 
Is there any daw software with loops with the functionality of changing the tracks notes accordingly to a chosen chord? 
For example, I add a loop and then change the chord of a part of the song, and then all the notes of that part are changed accordingly. Not just transposing, so for example I can change from a major chord to a minor. 
I tested garage band and I've had never played with loops before. But it seems to me it's missing a functionality like that.

Comment: You're looking for a kind of arpeggiator in a way.  You might be able to find something in VST or other plugin format a bit easier.  Ableton Live's functionality will get you close, but not quite what you are looking for, unless you wouldn't mind presetting a handful of the loops you need.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'm looking for an arpeggiator. I don't want the software to generate a lot of notes and broken chords, What I want is to change the notes I already have or the notes in the loops I added, according to the chord I select.

Comment: This question might be easier to follow if you were to incorporate some of your clarifications (in the comments below) directly into the text of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The piano roll in Fruit Loops Studio has the option to change your left click action from adding a single note to adding a chord. As well as all kind of variations of major, minor, diminished etc. it gives you 9th/11th chords to keep adding notes up and up the scale for a big sound.

It won't change any notes automatically as you change your song, but it does allow you to quickly flesh out a complex sound and accommodate alterations without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about MIDI loops or loops of audio?

For MIDI loops in any DAW, you could select all of the relevant notes and shift them to their correct positions, which takes relatively little time (for example, to change from major to minor chords, select all of the thirds and move them a half-step in the correct direction).

But for audio, there is no "perfect" way to use this, as pitch information isn't explicitly stored in a waveform.  There's a program that claims to do this kind of isolation called Melodyne DNA, if I remember correctly, but like timestretching and transposition algorithms, it isn't perfect and will leave behind some artifacts.  I don't know of any DAW software that offers this kind of functionality.

Comment: The plugin you mean would be Melodyne, by Celemony, which actually does a pretty good job in separating notes out of chords. I used it in several occasions and I was generally happy with what it was capable of.

Comment: I know in any daw I can edit the notes by hand... but that's not my question. I'm asking for some daw software that chanes all the notes automatically when I change the chord of a bar. About audio loops I know it can't be done. Just for midi.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Environment in Logic Studio you can create MIDI "devices" that will automatically force your playing into a particular key. 
I believe there are some built into Logic already.

Answer (score 0):

The software is not very sexy, but Band in a Box by PG Music might be useful. It has features to help with chords and chord progressions and accompanying your melody.